# how to grab the primary dark color from angular material or what are all color variables we can use with angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi how do we use the primary dark color from angular material?
I have used `color="p-dark"`  but it is not working.

How do we grab the dark color the material color tool has defined?
I would like to use the dark color that is defined with the following helper website:

https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=1&view.right=0&primary.color=FFF9C4

Do we have to define it in our custom theme?

Or could someone share all color variables that we can use with angular material?

Comment: Can you share the code sample?

Comment: ```<mat-form-field style="width: 100%" color="p-dark">
                <input matInput placeholder="E-Mail" [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher" />
            </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it is possible to do it directly with predefined CSS classes but here is how to do it in SCSS.

I suppose as a starting point that your theme is defined like this :

**my-material-theme.scss**

```css
[...]
$my-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);
```

Then, in your component SCSS :

**my.component.css**

```css
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import 'path/to/my-material-theme';


$color-config: mat.get-color-config($my-app-theme);

// get the chosen palette : primary, accent, warn
$primary-palette: map.get($color-config, 'primary');

.my-class {
  color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary-palette, 700);
}
```

More info in :

- [Theme your own components with Angular Material's theming system](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)
- [Reading hues from palettes](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#reading-hues-from-palettes)

Comment: Finally a helpful answer... I was so frustrated.